# No space left on device - Ubuntu 12.04 Server on VMware Workstation

Tags: 12.04, server, vmware-workstation

I have `Ubuntu 12.04 Server` installed and inside `VMWare WorkStation 10` and have much space left.

Even when I try to create a folder it says: -

```
No space left on device
```

I have much space allocated for my Virtual Machine but do not know what is going wrong.

Here is what someone suggested and here is output: -

[image]

Output of `df -h` is

[image]

Comment: I think it is issue with that machine in which you virtual box is installed can you share the result of you main machine by issue this command # df -h
# fdisk -L

Comment: You're listing inodes only, and only for `/`. Try `df -h` to show you the actual amount of space free, and for all mounted filesystems. Can you edit your question with the entire output of `df -h`?

Comment: @RobieBasak Edited....

Comment: Sorry, I only just noticed that you said this happened even if you tried to just create a folder. Could you also include the entire output of `df -i`, rather than just restricting it to `/`? Also, please describe the command you're using to create a directory and what directory you're in when you try to do this. It is on the same machine that you've shown the `df` output, right? Finally, check to see if anything is logged in `/var/log/kern.log` that might be relevant, especially if new messages appear when the create directory attempt fails.

Comment: I actually have restored to my previous snapshot and I am sure I am gonna have this problem again. I will tell you then.
By the way, where ever I try to create folder/file it says no disk space, even as a root